# Nested new result from entity framework query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a function that filters "Inspectors" by keywords and areas. The relation between "Inspectors" and "Areas" are many to many.

```
public IQueryable<Inspector> Search(string keywords, int? areaId)
{
    var qry = this.GetAllInspectors();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
       qry = qry.Search(keywords);

    if (areaId.HasValue)
       qry = qry.ByAreaId(areaId.Value);

    var search = from a in _entities.Areas
                 select new InspectorSearchResult
                 {
                     Area = i.Areas,
                     Inspectors = (.....).ToList()
                  };  // ??

    return qry.OrderBy(i => i.LastName).ThenBy(i => i.FirstName);
}
```

InspectorSearchResult.cs

```
public class InspectorSearchResult
{
    public Area Area { get; set; }
    public List<Inspector> Inspectors { get; set; }
}
```

How can I modify that query only get "inspectors by area" in nested form?

UPDATE:

Tried this but got: "... method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
public List<InspectorSearchResult> Search(string keywords, int? areaId)
{
       var qry = this.GetAllInspectors();

       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
          qry = qry.Search(keywords);

       if (areaId.HasValue)
          qry = qry.ByAreaId(areaId.Value);

       var search = from i in qry
                    from a in i.Areas
                    orderby a.AreaName
                    select new InspectorSearchResult
                     {
                         Area = a,
                         Inspectors = (from ins in a.Inspectors
                                       orderby ins.LastName, ins.FirstName
                                       select ins).ToList()
                     };

        return search.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: how do you POCOs look like ? Do you have a Navigation Property `public virtual ICollection<Inspector> Inspectors` (or something like that) in your Area class ?

Comment: Its 3.5 made so it has no poco's but you can access it with x.Area and  x.Inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?.

```
public List<InspectorSearchResult> Search(string keywords, int? areaId)
{
    var qry = this.GetAllInspectors();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords))
        qry = qry.Search(keywords);

    if (areaId.HasValue)
        qry = qry.ByAreaId(areaId.Value);

    var search = from i in qry
        from a in i.Areas
        orderby a.AreaName
        select new InspectorSearchResult
        {
            Area = a
        };

    foreach(var x in search)
    {
        x.Inspectors = (
            from ins in a.Inspectors
            orderby ins.LastName, ins.FirstName
            select ins)
            .ToList();
    }

    return search.ToList();
}
```